# Chemical reaction

Tags: chemfig, tikz-cd, chemistry, mhchem

Good morning, everyone,

I am a Bachelor of Science in Physics student, and I would like to be able to reproduce the routing of this example here on Latex, not necessarily draw the molecules, I learn on the job (thanks to the Net).

I tried with tikz, and chemfig, but I have something very academic, if not primary. Indeed, I would like to be able to draw the big arrow on the left and the three arrows down, vary their size.

This would allow me to build my own reactions.

Thank you very much.

I'm sorry, I forgot to insert the links

https://pubs.acs.org/na101/home/literatum/publisher/achs/journals/content/jpcafh/2008/jpcafh.2008.112.issue-5/jp709896w/production/images/medium/jp709896wh00001.gif

I'm interested in the middle arrow here, and here's the document I was talking about.

https://pubs.acs.org/na101/home/literatum/publisher/achs/journals/content/jpcafh/2008/jpcafh.2008.112.issue-5/jp709896w/production/images/medium/jp709896wh00002.gif

My simple routine :

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
& 0  \arrow{r}{a} \arrow{r}[swap]{b}                                  
& 1  \arrow{r}{a} \arrow{r}[swap]{b}                                  
& 2  \arrow{d}{a} \arrow{d}[swap]{b}                                                 
& \\
& 5  \arrow{d}{a} \arrow{d}[swap]{b}               
& 4  \arrow{l}{a} \arrow{l}[swap]{b}  
& 3  \arrow{l}{a} \arrow{l}[swap]{b}
&\\
& 6  \arrow{r}{a} \arrow{r}[swap]{b}
& 7  \arrow{r}{a} \arrow{r}[swap]{b}
& 8  \arrow{d}{a} \arrow{d}[swap]{b}
&\\
& 11                                                   
& 10 \arrow{l}{a} \arrow{l}[swap]{b} 
& 9  \arrow{l}{a} \arrow{l}[swap]{b}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE.

Comment: @AB: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)   Regarding "I tried with tikz, and chemfig": could you please add a MWE showing what you tried so far? Currently your question is  a _just-do-it-for-me_ with a quite vague description of the desired output given that the  linked image contains more than 10 arrows. Could you therefore please try to further clarify your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing that the question is about merged arrows, the following two small examples might serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
  A
  \arrow(a--b){->[Text2]}[,1.0]
  B
  \arrow(@a--c){->[][*{0} Text1]}[-90]
  C
   \merge>(c)(b)--()D
\schemestop

\bigskip

\schemestart
  A
  \arrow(a--b){->[Text2]}[,1.0]
  B
  \arrow(@a--c){->[][*{0} Text1]}[-90]
  C
  \arrow(@c--d){->[][Text3]}[,2.5]
  D
\schemestop
\makeatletter
\chemmove{
  \draw[-CF ,shorten <=\CF@arrow@offset,shorten >=\CF@arrow@offset]
    (b) |- node[pos=.7,right] {} (d) ;
}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for your valuable answer. I wanted to make a nice arrow on the left between 0 and 7, and one between 5 and 7 for example, without making a diagonal, as you showed me on your second example (thanks again for that)

Comment: @AB: Out of curiosity, do you want to draw the scheme of a chemical reaction sequence or are you just interested in the arrow that you need for a different scheme?

Comment: I plan to draw the scheme of chemical reaction sequence (like that : https://pubs.acs.org/na101/home/literatum/publisher/achs/journals/content/jpcafh/2008/jpcafh.2008.112.issue-5/jp709896w/production/images/medium/jp709896wh00002.gif), but I don't want to abuse the help and ask for all my work to be done. 
As I have a lot of difficulty drawing the arrows, to see straight away the reaction process as on the scientific article, it is my priority